# Removing a file in a branch in git implies removing it from the master branch as well?

Tags: git, branch

I just faced a situation that seems illogical to me with Git. I have a repo with a plenty of commits, so at this stage it has only one branch (*master*).

[image: Master branch]

Suppose this branch has a file called **MyFile.txt**. Now I need to create a different branch because I want to make some changes to a few files and I don't want to do it master branch directly, so I run:

```
git checkout iss53
```

Now the schema looks like this:

[image: New branch]

Fine, I have switched to branch *iss53*, I run `ls -l` and the *MyFile.txt*. One of the changes include deleting the *MyFile.txt* file, so:

```
git rm MyFile.txt
```

Nice, running `ls -l` again shows there's not *MyFile.txt* anymore. So I switch back to the *master* branch:

```
git checkout master
```

But... the *MyFile.txt* file has vanished as well. My logic says that if I deleted the file on a branch, it should be applied **only** to that branch, so why is the file deleted from the *master* branch as well? Note that I haven't made any commits yet, just branching.

**Note**: Both images are taken from [Git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in your question :

> Note that I haven't made any commits yet, just branching.

If you don't commit, the changes are always kept in your working directory. Switching the branch doesn't affect your working directory, and the working directory also doesn't affect your last commit. You are seeing that the file is deleted, but the reality that it is deleted from your working directory only. If you want to clear the changes and return to the last commit use this command :

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

So the file will be restored again.

Maybe it is not logic for you, but this behavior can be useful. Imagine that you have 2 branches : `master` and `development`, and you should always work on `development` before you move the changes to `master`. Let's say that you forgot to switch to `development` before starting working, then -before you commit- you realized that you are on `master`. The solution is simple, just switch to `development` then commit.

Comment: To use the right terminology, `git rm` removed the file from the **index**, a staging area for changes ready to be committed. Note that git will always let you switch between branches with uncommitted changes (in your worktree or index) if they don't conflict with the changes between the branches. You can see the changed files in worktree and index using `git status`, and see the diffs of the changes in index with `git diff --cached`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I removed a file from one of my branches (which I called login) it didn't remove it from the master branch.

1. I switched to the login branch `git checkout login`
2. Removed the test.html file `git rm --cached test.html`
3. Added everything to the staging area `git add .`
4. Committed the changes with `git commit -m 'removed test.html file'`
5. Pushed the local repo to the Github remote repo with `git push`